# How to proof this formula about Euler constant: $\gamma=\int_0^1\frac1{x+1}\sum\limits_{v=0}^\infty x^{2^v-1}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

$$\gamma=\int_0^1\frac1{x+1}\sum_{v=0}^\infty x^{2^v-1}dx$$

Too hard for me to solve it

Comment: Maybe you can interchange the sum and integral? Also [please post at least some background information and what you tried](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please take moment to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: As a hint, note that we have $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^v+k}=\begin{cases}\log 2, & v=0, \\[0.25em] H_{2^v-1}-H_{2^{v-1}-1}-\log 2, & v\geq 1,\end{cases}$$ where $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$ is the harmonic number. Also, it seems that this is known as [Catalan's integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html#eqn28).

Comment: See the proof from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html.